# Show that $E[1/X] = 1/E[X]$ using Jensen's inequality

Tags: proof-verification, jensen-inequality

The function $1/x$ is convex on the interval $x > 0$ and two times differentiable.  So, for $x > 0$, Jensen's inequality implies

$$E(1/x) \geq 1/E(x).$$

But for $x < 0$, $1/x$ is not convex, but concave.  However, $1/(-x)$ is convex and two times differentiable.  Let $g(x) = f(-x) = -1/x$.  Then

\begin{align}
   E(g(x)) &\geq g(E(x))\\
   E(f(-x)) &\geq f(-E(x))\\
   E(-1/x) &\geq -1/E(x)\\
   - E(-1/x) &\leq 1/E(x)
\end{align}

I continue by giving a geometric argument that $-E(-1/x) = E(1/x)$.  So

$$E(1/x) \leq 1/E(x).$$

I'm OK with showing the convexity and differentiability of the function, but I'm not OK with this argument, in particular this last step that I'm trying to give a geometric argument using reflections.  Can you shed some light?  Thanks!

Comment: The statement you're trying to prove is false in general. Good luck finding a satisfying argument.

Comment: I must have copied it wrong.  Then the statement must be $E(1/x) \geq 1/E(x)$ because $1/x$ is convex (for $x > 0$). So I must make this restriction $x > 0$.  Do you agree?  Thank you! @Raskolnikov

Comment: That'd be fine then.

Comment: Hey, look.  Instead of reflections, I can say that $E$ is a linear function and so $E(-f(x)) = -E(f(x))$ which implies $-E(-f(x)) = E(f(x))$.  This would complete the argument above, so what's wrong?  I do believe the result for the moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is true that if a random variable $X$ takes on positive values only then
$$E\left[\frac{1}{X}\right] \ge \frac{1}{E[X]}, \tag{1}$$
and 
$$E\left[\frac{1}{X}\right] \le \frac{1}{E[X]}, \tag{2}$$
when $X$ takes on negative values only. But $(1)$ and $(2)$ do not imply that $$E\left[\frac{1}{X}\right] = \frac{1}{E[X]} \tag{3}$$
because $(1)$ and $(2)$ hold for different types of RVs: $(1)$ for positive and $(2)$ for negative RVs.

Comment: What is meant by RV?

Comment: It must be [r]andom [v]ariable.

Comment: @JoepAwinita Yes, RV stands for a random variable.